# Change symbolic links

Tags: perl, symlink

I need to change all symbolic links in a given directory to use the shortest relative path.

Example:
change

```
kat/../kat/link
```

or

```
usr/sth/sth/kat/link
```

into

```
kat/link
```

How can I do this using Perl?

Comment: not pearl..It is Perl

Comment: at the moment i have only checking, if dir is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a simplified path by using `abs_path` and then removing the current directory to make it relative:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd qw/getcwd abs_path/;

my $silly_path = 'foo/../foo/../foo/../foo';

my $simplified = abs_path($silly_path);
my $cwd = getcwd();

print "Canonical path: $simplified\n";
print "Current directory: $cwd\n";

$simplified =~ s|^\Q$cwd/||;    #Make relative if within current directory.

print "Simplified path: $simplified\n";
```

This assumes that the links are in Perl's current working directory. You could replace that with another directory if you want.  It will result in the relative path for a link within the current directory, or a simplified absolute path for something that points outside the current directory.

You can get all files in a directory using [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), then use the `-l $file` [file test operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to test if `$file` is a symbolic link.